# Writing a driver to fool Linux systems about having a GPU

Tags: c, linux, driver, x11

I'm into something about writing a "Mock GPU driver" for Linux based systems. What I mean is that, simply I want to write a driver (Behind X-server obviously) to answer X's API calls with some debugging messages.

In other words I want to fool Linux about having an actual GPU. So I can make a test-bed for GUI-accelerated packages in console based systems.

Right now, if I execute a GUI-accelerated package in Linux console based systems; it'll simply dies due to lack of a real GPU (or a GPU driver better I'd say).

**So I want to know:**

- Is it even possible? (Writing a GPU driver to fool Linux about having an actual GPU)
- What resources do you recommend before getting my hands dirty in code?
- Is there any similar projects around the net?

PS: I'm an experienced ANSI-C programmer but I don't have any clue in real Kernel/Driver development under *nix (read some tutorials about USB driver development though), so any resources about these areas will be really appreciated as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you actually interested in seeing those 'debug' messages or just want the apps to run? For the latter, there are virtual X servers.

Comment: Yes, I'm interested actually, but would you please give me some links to those virtual X server projects? thanks in advance.

Comment: Some OpenCL implementations are able to run on the CPU only.

Comment: @3p3r: that server is actually included in Xorg, and it is called `Xvfb` ([manpage](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/Xvfb/)). If you're not afraid of some bash, you can look at Gentoo's [virtualx.eclass](http://sources.gentoo.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/gentoo-x86/eclass/virtualx.eclass?view=markup#l96) for an example of use (there it is used to run tests which require X11).

Comment: @MichałGórny That's the exact thing I'm looking for! put it in an answer please, and I'll accept it :D thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is actually part of Xorg server suite, and it is called [Xvfb](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/Xvfb/) (virtual framebuffer).

If you're not afraid of a bit complex bash, you can take a look at Gentoo's [virtualx.eclass](http://sources.gentoo.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/gentoo-x86/eclass/virtualx.eclass?view=markup#l96) for an use example (we use it to run tests which require X11).

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start is the Mesa project - it implements OpenGL in software. It has a way to trick the OS into thinking that it is the OpenGL driver.

Comment: Mesa is in software-level I think, It's "after" X-server not "Before" it. I mean this package calls X's APIs, right? it's somehow a "Redirect"or of OpenGL calls, right?

Comment: Mesa will run on top of Xvfb, thus you can have an entire 3D X server running without any graphics hardware. This won't help you with development of non-X projects, like accelerated consoles, though! Mesa and Xvfb do not provide a kernel-level graphics card abstraction.